# Chrome profile not loading with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\shahr\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

I tried this from other StackOverFlow Answers, but it refuses to open the desired profile

Comment: Try to remove options.argument.

Comment: @bonifacio_kid what do you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\robert.car\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

chrom_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

user-data-dir considers profile as default , and you don't have to specify that . If its something else specify it through profile-directory argument

**Step to create a profile:**

**open** : chrome://version in address bar

[image]

**copy** the user dir folder completely to eg c:\tmp\newdir

open the copied user data (newdir) and search for folder called Default . This is the profile folder.

**rename** the Default folder as "Profile 1"

**Now to use this :**

```
chrom_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=c:\\tmp\\newdir")

chrom_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
```