# How to pass profile with stored login information to selenium and force an auto login process

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to import my *Chrome* profile for use in *chromedriver*. I want to use the stored login information in that profile to automatically log in to Facebook using *selenium*.

My current code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('C:\\Users\\Jose Vitor\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
```

This code opens *Chrome* using *chromedriver*, but 
[it creates 3 blank tabs and Facebook is not logged into automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geflg.png)

Could someone help me solve the automatic login process to Facebook using *chromedriver* with a stored profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

---

I could not get the stored login for Facebook to pass to a profile in *selenium*.  So I put together some login code for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

# global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
username_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="email"]')
username_box.send_keys('username')

password_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="pass"]')
password_box.send_keys('password')

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login"))).click()
```

### ORIGINAL POST

---

Here is some code that only opens 1 tab and pass your profile.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# you need to verify this path on your Windows systems.
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google Chrome/User Data")

chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
```

Have you tried to write any code around logging into Facebook after Chrome opens? if not, looks at some of these past questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=login+into+facebook+with+selenium+python

Comment: if it was loading the profile was working, all saved passwords and sites where the login is saved would be opening with the user logged in right?

Comment: @JoseVitorGravena The code above will pass your profile to selenium, but I'm not sure about the saved passwords.  I NEVER save passwords in my browsers, so I would have to test this functionality.

Comment: @JoseVitorGravena I'm not sure if you can do an auto login by passing your profile.  I have tried it multiple times and I couldn't get it to work.  I added some login code for facebook to my answer.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: @JoseVitorGravena did you try my code?

Comment: yesss it works!!! THANKS!!!

Comment: @JoseVitorGravena GREAT!!  [Please accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 0):

open chrome that works without needing to login to facebook and run `chrome://version/` and then copy the highlighted part:

[image]

Close all chrome instance and use: (Dont give last directory )

```
options.add_argument(--user-data-dir='C:\\Users\\Jose Vitor\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data');
```

This will use your default chrome profile it will have your login information . You may not have created profile correctly don't give profile-directory when using default as it will be taken automatically

Comment: selenium will create a new profile (e.g. Profile 2) and it will use some of the items from the profile (e.g., Profile 1) being passed.  Each time I try to use a stored password it does not pass to the site linked that account info.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex if you pass a profile then selenium will not create a profile . It will be created only if nothing is passed or given profile doesn't exists

Comment: in the above mentioned case it will not create profile but use your default profile which has the saved session

Comment: it won't use anything from profile 1 in profile 2 , it will be a new profile with user-data folder same . But sessions might not work as there will session details inside profile folder also . so you have to use both userdata and profile

Comment: My code passes a profile that has saved login info, but that info isn't passed to the service.  When I look at the profile it is new with no saved login details.  When I check the other profiles there is NO saved login info.

Comment: please add the code you used

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65140078/6793637

Comment: My code is in my answer.

Comment: there might not be any profile 2 thats why its creating a new one , if you login to facebook in that stage then for second automation run it should not ask for password

Comment: I removed the OPs Windows variables from my answer. The login info is not being passed and it is saved in the Chrome outside of selenium.  In selenium that information does not exist when being passed.

Comment: I looked through https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues.  I don't think it is possible to auto login by passing a profile to chromedriver.  I voted to reopen this question, because that is what the OP asked to do.